# Unable to parse two fields from a webpage using requests module

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape two fields `product_title` and `item_code` from this [webpage](https://www.sainsburys.co.uk/gol-ui/Product/persil-small---mighty-non-bio-laundry-liquid-21l-60-washes) using requests module. When I execute the script below, I always get `AttributeError` in place of the result as the data I'm after are not in page source.

However, I've come across several solutions in here which are able to fetch data from javascript encrypted sites even when the data are not in page source, so I suppose there should be any way to grab the two fields from the webpage using requests.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://www.sainsburys.co.uk/gol-ui/Product/persil-small---mighty-non-bio-laundry-liquid-21l-60-washes'

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36'
    res = s.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    product_title = soup.select_one("h1[data-test-id='pd-product-title']").get_text(strip=True)
    item_code = soup.select_one("span#productSKU").get_text(strip=True)
    print(product_title,item_code)
```

Expected output:

```
Persil Non-Bio Laundry Liquid 1.43L
Item code: 7637944
```

> How can I fetch the two fields from that site using requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the wesite calling apis, so you can use that directly to get the data

```py
r = requests.get('https://www.sainsburys.co.uk/groceries-api/gol-services/product/v1/product?filter[product_seo_url]=gb%2Fgroceries%2Fpersil-small---mighty-non-bio-laundry-liquid-21l-60-washes&include[ASSOCIATIONS]=true&include[PRODUCT_AD]=citrus')
products = r.json()['products']

for each_product in products:
    print(f"Item code: {each_product['product_uid']}")
    print(each_product['name'])
    
    
# Item code: 7637944
# Persil Non-Bio Laundry Liquid 1.43L
```